# Parse the template in powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I wanted to parse the below template based on my parameters in powershell.

```
param(
 [string]$servicePrincipalId="e90a1407-55c3-432d-9cb1-3638900a9d22",
 [string]$azureSubscriptionId="123",
 [string]$resourceGroupName=245,
 [string]$vnetName=456
)

  Write-Host '{
  "Name":"AtlasPeering/($azureSubscriptionId)/$resourceGroupName/$vnetName",
 "IsCustom":true,
  "Description":"manage peering connections on network ",
 "Actions":[
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/read",
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/write",
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/delete",
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action"
  ]
}'
```

The above template should print like below

```
 {
   "Name":"AtlasPeering/123/245/456",
  "IsCustom":true,
  "Description":"manage peering connections on network",
  "Actions":[
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/read",
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/write",
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/delete",
  "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Use double quotes to expand variables inside write-host, enclose internal double quotes in `"

Answer (score 1):

Try making the output string a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1#here-strings):

```
Write-Host @"
{
 "Name":"AtlasPeering/($azureSubscriptionId)/$resourceGroupName/$vnetName",
 "IsCustom":true,
 "Description":"manage peering connections on network ",
 "Actions":[
   "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/read",
   "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/write",
   "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings/delete",
   "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/peer/action"
 ]
}
"@
```